# on check/uncheck of checkbox add/delete a number in/from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am saving  mobile numbers in array on check of checkbox and removing the mobile number when unchecked.

I tried this but it is not deleting the exact number which is unchecked.

```
var $this = $(this);

var index = parseInt($this.attr("_idx").slice(1));
console.log("index"+index);

if (index >=0 && index < recep.length) {

    recep.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("to2"+recep);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var mobileNoArray = [];
  $(".mob-no").click(function(event){
    var selectedNo = $(event.target).val();
    var index = $.inArray(selectedNo, mobileNoArray); 
    if (index != -1) {// means found so pop it 
        mobileNoArray.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        mobileNoArray.push(selectedNo);
    }
    console.log(mobileNoArray);
    alert(mobileNoArray);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="9999999999" class="mob-no"/>
mob-1
</label>

<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="8888888888" class="mob-no"/>
mob-2
</label>

<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="7777777777" class="mob-no"/>
mob-3
</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: searched in stackoverflow for long and finally found one which works like a charm....